# displays undefined after array is finished

Tags: javascript

This is one of my first projects, I'm trying to have a countdown after the "start" button is presssed from 3,2,1,Stream! then display the times x, and z are tapped on the doc, but after "Stream!" it displays undefined. It feels like I've tried everything in my current knowledge, if you can help, Thanks!

```js
var sec = ["3", "2", "1", "Stream!"];
var a = 0;
var xcount = 0;
var zcount = 0;
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", updatetimer);
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyPush);

function updatetimer() {
    var time = setInterval(timer, 1000, false);
}

function keyPush(evt) {
    switch (evt.keyCode) {
        case 88:
            xcount = xcount + 1;
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xcount;
            break;
        case 90:
            zcount = zcount + 1;
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = zcount;
            break;
    }
}

function timer() {
    var write = (document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = sec[a]);
    a += 1;
    if (write === sec[3]) {
        clearInterval(time);
        return;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>

  <input type="button" value="Start!" id="myBtn"/>
  <p id="demo"> </p>
  <p1 id ="demo2"> </p1>

</html>
```

Comment: look in the **developer** tools console ... `ReferenceError: time is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

The `time` was within the scope of `updatetimer()` only, you cannot use it else where. Put it in global.

```
var sec = ["3", "2", "1", "Stream!"];
var a = 0;
var xcount = 0;
var zcount = 0;
document.getElementById('myBtn').addEventListener("click", updatetimer);
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyPush);

var time;    //declare the reference to the timer in global so that you can clear it in another function.

function updatetimer() {
    time = setInterval(timer, 1000, false);

}

function keyPush(evt) {
switch (evt.keyCode) {
case 88:
  xcount = xcount + 1;
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML= xcount;
  break;
 case 90:
  zcount = zcount + 1;
   document.getElementById('demo2').innerHTML= zcount;
  break;
 }
}

function timer() {
    var write = document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = sec[a];
    a += 1;
    if (write === sec[3]) {
         clearInterval(time);
         return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function updatetimer() {
  var time = setInterval(timer, 1000, false);

}
```

time is scoped to updatetimer function and is not clearing.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined the variable `time` - hence the `undefined` message. You can do this:

```
var time;

function updateTimer() {
    time = setInterval(timer, 1000, false);
}
```

Plus, the empty global variable `time` means you can use time inside of other functions without redefining it as a local inside those functions first.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to declare `timer` variable in global scope. here [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp) has very simple example. Try it Yourself.

```js
var sec = ["3", "2", "1", "Stream!"];
var a = 0;
var xcount = 0;
var zcount = 0;
var timer;
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", updatetimer);
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyPush);

function updatetimer() {
    time = setInterval(timer, 1000, false);
}

function keyPush(evt) {
    switch (evt.keyCode) {
        case 88:
            xcount = xcount + 1;
            document.getElementById("xCount").innerHTML = xcount;
            break;
        case 90:
            zcount = zcount + 1;
            document.getElementById("zCount").innerHTML = zcount;
            break;
    }
}

function timer() {
    var write = (document.getElementById("countDown").innerHTML = sec[a]);
    a += 1;
    if (write === sec[3]) {
        clearInterval(time);
        return;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>

  <input type="button" value="Start!" id="myBtn"/>
  <p id="countDown"> </p>
  <p>X count: <span id="xCount"> </span></p>
  <p>Z count: <span id ="zCount"> </span></p>

</html>
```

> I have modified your code a little bit for more clarification.